# Any tricks for a huge shader nodes trees to become faster?

Tags: texturing, shaders, shader-nodes

I've noticed one interesting moment: each time I create some complex shaders they always slow down my Blenders viewport. At the same time, sometimes when I purchase any plugins that include complex and even bigger shaders they work fast and updates in real-time. So I wonder... Which nodes should I avoid while creating big node trees? Or are there any tricks that help to improve the shader speed? Should I use groups inside the groups? Any noises that should be replaced or maybe I shouldn't copy the group input node (I've read somewhere that it won't affect the speed) etc...

2. I've noticed that people use UVMaps to replace a gradient texture node. It looks like this:

But is it actually better to use this node instead of a Gradient Texture node? And how can I create it? >_<

[image]

It is not a first-time issue to me. So I don't post a direct example. But just to show an idea here is my shader vs the one with a quite similar result that I've got with some plugin (mine is the black one and it is way slower. How come?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I’ve noticed that Noise Texture can really cripple performance in Eevee (or material preview mode - which also uses Eevee) and this is far worse the higher the ‘Dimensions’ is set. Minimise the Dimension where possible - eg, don’t use the default ‘3d’ when only using 2d UV coordinates (I don’t know if that’s applicable in your case). I presume Musgrave may have the same implications since it is also noise-based. I presume this is due to Eevee caching the noise to attempt to improve performance for the actual rendering.

Comment: It looks like some of your textures have high detail values, I can't really see, though.

Comment: What about texture coordinates node? Are there some types of outputs more resource-intensive than others? Or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: I don't think it really matters for the Texture Coordinates - they're all pretty low overhead. Does it make much difference whether your rendering in Eevee or Cycles (you'll have to use Rendered view otherwise it will use Eevee anyway).